# How to programmatically change selected tabItem Header colour from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a program in which I have to load colours at startup.
Then I have to add a tabcontrol with tab items:

```
TabControl tabc = m_Executer.GetTabControl();<---- from outside
if (tabc != null)
{
    TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
    tbi.Header.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    tbi.Header.Content = "End manager";
    tabc.Items.Add(tbi);
    tabc.SelectionChanged += (sender2, args) =>
    {
        ((TabItem)(tabc.SelectedItem)).Background = Brushes.Red;
        tabc.UpdateLayout();
    };
}
```

the idea is changing the background when the selectionchanged event is fired but that doesn't work.

Comment: Your TabItem most likely contains a Grid or a similar container with a Background of its own.

Comment: Very Sorry I mean the header

Comment: Why dont use WPF styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a textblock to change color:

```
TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
tbi.Header = Brushes.Transparent;
TextBlock tbk = new TextBlock() { Text="End manager" };
tbi.Header = tbk;
    tabc.Items.Add(tbi);
```

and then change the textblock on the event

```
tabc.SelectionChanged += (sender2, args) =>
{

    ((TabItem)(tabc.SelectedItem)).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    tabc.UpdateLayout();

};
```

---

EDIT you'd better de-highlight the unselected items:

```
tabc.SelectionChanged += (sender2, args) =>
{
    foreach (var item in tabc.Items)
    {
        if (item == ((TabItem)(tabc.SelectedItem)))
            ((TabItem)item).Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        else
        ((TabItem)item).Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }                   
};
```

Comment: The edit was because if you don't change the color you will get all elements red after having selected.

Answer (score 3):

The default control template for a TabItem contains two Border elements named "mainBorder" and an "innerBorder". You could change the Background of the latter one:

```
tabc.SelectionChanged += (sender2, args) =>
{
    if(args.AddedItems != null && args.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        TabItem ti = args.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
        if(ti != null && VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ti) > 0)
        {
            Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ti, 0) as Grid;
            if (grid != null)
            {
                Border mainBorder = grid.Children[0] as Border;
                if (mainBorder != null)
                {
                    Border innerBorder = mainBorder.Child as Border;
                    if(innerBorder != null)
                        innerBorder.Background = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
       }
   }
};
```

The above code works on Windows 10. The templates may differ between different versions of Windows.

If you want to change the background of the unselected TabItem you simply replace `AddedItems` with `RemovedItems` and set the Background property of the `mainBorder`.

Comment: Are you using a custom TabItem style then or are you running on an older version of Windows? It certainly works for me on Windows 10.

Comment: Sorry no style and win7 x64

Comment: You should read my post again then. The templates differ between Windows 7 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `Content` to `TextBlock` instead of a string:

**XAML:**

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Items>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="Foo"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Bar" />
    </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```

or code behind (for whatever reason...)

```
TabItem tbi = new TabItem();
TextBlock headerElement = new TextBlock();
headerElement.Text = "End manager";
headerElement.Background = Brushes.Red;
tbi.Header = headerElement;
```

I also suggest you do take a deep dive into the MVVM pattern. In 98% of the cases it's best practice to write your UIs in XAML and bind to a ViewModel.

BTW: Your code doesn't even compile as `Header`is of type `object`...